# Poisson Probability Distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, poisson-distribution

You observe 9 cities and count the number of hurricanes that occur in each one and get the following:

Number of hurricanes: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8
Number of cities: 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0

What's the poisson probability density for these results, for the following lambda values:

2, 2.5, 3, 4, 5

I have that the formula for poisson is $\frac{e^-\lambda(λ^k)}{k!}$ and λ is the mean, which for my case is $\frac{30}{9}$.

Edit: So for a mean of say, 2.5, would I do the summation of $\frac{e^-2.5(2.5^{k_i})}{k_i!}$ where k is, as described in the answer below, 1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5, and 6? How would I go about getting the Poisson Probability density for 2.5, specifically?

Comment: I don't really understand what the question means by "the Poisson probability density for these results". Obviously it means probability *mass*, not *density*, but other than that I do not really understand the terminology. The likelihood function seems to be the only thing that makes sense and actually uses the data.

Answer (score 1):

We have the following random sample of $X$ which is assumed to have $\mathrm{Pois}(\lambda)$ distribution for some $\lambda>0$:

$$x = (1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,6) $$

Since $\mathbb E[X]=\lambda$, using the method of moments yields

$$\lambda = \bar x = \frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n x_i = \frac{10}3. $$

The maximum likelihood estimate is $$\hat\lambda := \arg\max\left\{\prod_{i=1}^n f(x_i;\lambda):\lambda\in(0,\infty) \right\} $$ where $$ f(x_i;\lambda) = e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^{x_i}}{x_i!}.$$ 
Since the logarithm is an increasing function, it is equivalent to maximize the log-likelihood function: $$\ell(\lambda) = \log\left(\prod_{i=1}^n e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^{x_i}}{x_i!}\right) = -n\lambda +\log\lambda\sum_{i=1}^n x_i +\sum_{i=1}^n \log x_i. $$
Differentiating with respect to $\lambda$ yields
$$\frac{\mathsf d \ell(\lambda)}{\mathsf d\lambda} = -n+\frac1\lambda\sum_{i=1}^n x_i.$$
It is clear that the derivative is equal to zero if and only if $\lambda = \bar x$. Moreover, the second derivative is
$$\frac{\mathsf d^2 \ell(\lambda)}{\mathsf d\lambda^2}  =-\frac1{\lambda^2}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i < 0$$ for all $\lambda$, so $\hat\lambda = \bar x$ is indeed the MLE.

I don't know why the question asks to fit Poisson distributions with means $2$, $\frac52$, and $3$, but clearly those are biased estimators...

Comment: well it goes on to list a lot more means afterwards, I just gave a few examples

Comment: But, say, for the mean of 2.5, how would I go about solving that one?

Comment: would I just find the sum of e^-2.5(2.5^x)/x! for the 9 values of x?

Comment: I think the question is just to evaluate the likelihood function at those particular values of $\lambda$.

Comment: Could you give an example of how to calculate that for one specific lambda, say 3?

Comment: I know it was stated in the answer but the notation is a little complex

Comment: It is just $\prod_{i=1}^9 e^{-\lambda} \frac{\lambda^{x_i}}{x_i!}$ where $x$ is given as in the top of this answer. $\prod$ is the notation for a product, it means you multiply all of the terms in the given range together.

Comment: Ok I will try to calculate it for 3 and get back to you

Comment: is there a product calculator that can do this? wolfram alpha probably? but the xis aren't 1,2,3,..,9 rather 1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,6

Comment: ill just do it on my calculator

Comment: It'd be easiest to do it in software like Matlab or Excel.

Comment: I got 2.0477E-8 for lambda = 2.5

Comment: @Ian I am guessing I made an error

Comment: No, likelihood functions of samples of any significant size tend to be pretty small, even near their maximum.

Comment: Before I go on calculating the rest of the lambdas, would you mind confirming my result?

Comment: Also would the max likelihood estimate for lambda = expected number of hurricanes per city = 10/3?