# Prove that $[2,4)$ is not compact.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, compactness

Prove that $[2,4)$ is not compact. Use the negation of compactness.

Looking to see if this is correct or if there is a more elegant proof.

My solution: To show that $[2,4)$ is not compact, we must show that there exists an open cover, which does not have a finite sub cover. Take the open cover $(2-\frac{1}{n}, 4-\frac{1}{n})$ where $n \in\mathbb{N}$. We must show that this open cover does not have a finite sub cover. $(2-\frac{1}{n}, 4-\frac{1}{n})$ does not have a finite sub cover, because if it did, then there would exist $n_k$ such that $(2-\frac{1}{n_k}, 4-\frac{1}{n_k})$ covers $[2,4)$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. But $(2-\frac{1}{n_k}, 4-\frac{1}{n_k})$ does not cover $(2-\frac{1}{n_{k+1}}, 4-\frac{1}{n_{k+1}})$. Thus $[2,4)$ is not compact.

Comment: It's enough to prove the set isn't closed. Why not just a sequence that approaches $4$ from the left?

Comment: A subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is compact iff it is closed and bounded.

Comment: It wants you to prove it by using the negation of the definition of compactness

Comment: Isn't it clear from the context that the OP doesn't want to or can't use Heine-Borel?

Comment: Sorry, should have clarified.

Comment: Correction: "there would exist $n_k$ such that...covers $\bf{[2,4)}$." The last sentence needs improvement. Exhibit an $x \in [2,4)$ such that $x \notin \cup_{k} (2 - \frac{1}{n_k}, 4 - \frac{1}{n_k}) $.

Comment: @PaulFrost, please don't edit large numbers of old questions over short periods. It knocks new questions off the front page.

Comment: @GerryMyerson You are right, I did not think about this effect. Thank you for your comment. My intention was to remove inadequate tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is almost right.

Suppose $(2-\frac{1}{n},4-\frac{1}{n})$ has a finite subcover of $[2,4)$ then there exists and $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\cup_{n=1}^{N} (2-\frac{1}{n},4-\frac{1}{n})$ cover $[2,4)$, but that union is $(1,4-\frac{1}{N})$, so points very close to 4 in $[2,4)$ are not in that union.

Indeed, $4-\frac{1}{2N}$ is in $[2,4)$ but not in $(1,4-\frac{1}{N})$.

Comment: The finite subcover may not need all sets from $n=1$ to $n=N$ but that "extra" sets doesn't affect the fact that it is a finite subcover.

Comment: @Antioquia3943 yeah. Sorry for not having read your answer properly.

Comment: 2-1/n < 2 < 4 - 1/n for all n, no?

Comment: @JohnH You're right.

Comment: @Antioquia3943 That has me thinking. Does it matter than (1,3) does not cover (1,4) or since we take an infinite amount of n, it would?

Comment: @JohnH Doesn't matter, you just need that all your union to cover $[2,4)$, and that union is $(1,4)$.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Thought so.

Comment: My bad: I misread it with was $2+\frac1n$...

Comment: Figured. All good.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli Are you familiar with poisson probability distributions?

Comment: @JohnH Very little. Why?

Comment: Had a question involving that but didn't get the answer I was looking for http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1969077/poisson-probability-distribution

Comment: If you happen to know how to approach this problem, that'd be appreciated. No worries if not.